# GMail as mail-in database for attachments?

Tags: gmail, attachments, google-docs

I'm a teacher and I get students to submit work by email. It would be great if anything they attach could automatically be added to my Google Docs with their name or email address as a label, without my having to manually open each mail and click each attachment. Are there any tools out there that could help me with this? Any other Web 2.0 solution available?

Many thanks,

J

Answer (score 3):

You could use the feature to sent documents directly to Google Docs via email. Just open Google Docs, choose **Upload** and scroll down to the bottom of the page. There you will see a **unique email address** to which your students can email their documents; the name of the document is the email subject.

You can read a bit more about it in [this](http://lifehacker.com/217832/upload-google-docs-via-email) Lifehacker article.

To have some structuring to the received documents, you can ask your students to add their name or an ID to the mail subject. After that, all you need to do is create [saved searches](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93297) for each student you have. The saved searches will act as a sort of label. It's not perfect, but it can save you a bit of time :)

Comment: There are some limitations : documents up to 500KB and no spreadsheets, PDF files, and Microsoft Office 2007 formats.

Comment: @harrymc True, but the limitations are there even if you upload documents from your hard drive directly. There's no way to bypass some of these restrictions, however you try to upload files.

Comment: @alex: you're right. Your method is perfect, but Justin will have to limit his students' document size, so google docs might not be acceptable for him in the end.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. If I could label the incoming files on the basis of sender email address then it would be perfect. Not sure if I can though. Thanks Alex.

Comment: No labeling, unfortunately. But you can ask your students to add their name in the mail subject. That way, you can just search for the documents using their name. It's not exactly a label, but it's not that bad :). You can create a saved search with the student name you want. It acts almost like a label.